# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions'

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I have done an upgrade of an `Asp.Net Core` application from `beta 7` to `RC1` by following the steps outlined in these two guidelines:

[Beta 7 to Beta 8](http://wildermuth.com/2015/10/20/Upgrading_from_ASP_NET_5_Beta_7_to_Beta_8)

[Beta 8 to RC 1](http://wildermuth.com/2015/11/18/Upgrading_ASP_NET_5_Beta_8_to_RC1)

After the conversion the application compiles, but on startup I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As can be seen in the screenshot below this exception occurs in `UseBrowserLink`.

[image]

Here is the dependency listing in my project.json file:

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
   "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
   "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
   "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
   "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},

"commands": {
   "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
   "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this exception and how I could go about resolving it?

UPDATE:

Here is the output from when I start the application from `Visual Studio`:

'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Host.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource\4.0.0-beta-23516\lib\dotnet5.2\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.DesignTime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'SubjectChooser'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\6.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\EntityFramework.Core\7.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\EntityFramework.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer\7.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework\3.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity\3.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime\4.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Routing\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.MemoryPool\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.MemoryPool.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor\4.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Cors\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Ix-Async\1.2.5\lib\net45\System.Interactive.Async.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Remotion.Linq\2.0.1\lib\net45\Remotion.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq.Expressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\EntityFramework.Relational\7.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\EntityFramework.Relational.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors\4.1.1-beta-23516\lib\portable-net45+win8\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuth\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuth.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader\14.0.0-rc1-final\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\bruce_000.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity\7.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\dnx451\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'.

UPDATE 2:

It seems that somewhere in Visual Studio there is a reference to a `beta 7` version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll`. The file referenced is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\dnx451`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How do I go about removing this reference or updating it to RC1?

Comment: (1) You should never ever have to reference `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime`. The only thing you might need is `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`. (2) What dnx version are you using?

Comment: I only put that in trying to fix this problem. I still get the problem with `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime` removed.

Comment: When I did "dnvm upgrade" as per the instructions in the guideline the upgrade was done to version `1.0.0-rc1-update1`. Under project properties in `Visual Studio` I have this version selected for `Solution DNX SDK version`

Comment: Can you please run the app from a console (`dnx web`)? But, before doing that set the environment variable `DNX_TRACE` = 1. Then share the output with us.

Comment: It only seems to go wrong inside Visual Studio; `dnx web` starts without problems. I will copy the output from Visual Studio as an update to the question.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest VS and tooling

Comment: I installed `Asp.Net 5 RC` from here: https://get.asp.net/ Does this include update 1 and the tooling?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with tooling because one of the last lines in the log mentions `Web Tools\Page Inspector`

Comment: Could my issue be related to this comment (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4228ca7-63e3-42c3-9830-a6bc06345c4b/is-page-inspector-available-in-visual-studio-2015-rc?forum=visualstudiogeneral) about page inspector being missing in `Visual Studio 2015 RC`? But my project clearly has a reference to an old version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll` in a `Page Inspector` subfolder. (See my latest update)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I used here was to simply delete the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.dll` that was being referenced by `Visual Studio`. When the file was gone the exception did not appear. Not the ideal solution but it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader to project dependencies in project.json file.